# custom TextView that can change background color

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a written a custom TextView in kotlin, which acts as a selection button. 
Meaning, in unselected states it has a grey-ish background with corners, and in selected state it this background changes color.

(In the middle of the button there's a text)

**The problem :** 
I need to display a whole group of these buttons, and for each button, the color of selected state can vary and change from button to button.

So if I have : Button1, Button2, Button3, for each of them, when they're selected, the background color is different.

Can I somehow control the color that the drawable xml uses?

button_background :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/dynamicColor" /> --> how can I control this color?

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: you can create a StateListDrawable, it has status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the `Solid color` of the drawable file programmatically. like the following.

```
val drawable = view.getBackground() as GradientDrawable // here view is your textview reference.
drawable.setColor(Color.GREEN) // set your color here
```

Comment: Thank you, it is minimalistic and does exactly what I need.
I actually tried using GradientDrawable but it crashed. Weird, I might have missed something.
Anyway, as my question was for Kotlin, please add the kotlin version, when using inside the Custom View class :
`drawable = background as GradientDrawable `
and `drawable.setColor(Color.Green)`

Comment: I have updated my answer for kotlin. You can also upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the res/drawable/ folder create a `BtnStateDrawable.xml`, then set different status ShapeDrawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource" . //here is your shapedrawable
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

Comment: thank you, the second solution is a bit more convenient to use, so I accepted it. Nevertheless, I will definitely check out this solution too.